# ClientAbortException on Jersey REST resource

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I added a new method to my REST resource (Jersey). When I'm trying to test it I fails with:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

When I'm debugging it, I can see that my code gets to the return statement, by somewhere afterwards fail.
BTW, I have many other methods that works just fine, all return JSON objects.

This happened when I'm trying to call the new method from Jersey Client or simply from a web browser.

My code:

```
@GET
@Path("/metrics/samples")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MetricSamples getFragmentMetricsSamples(@DefaultValue ("-1") @QueryParam ("from")long from, @DefaultValue ("-1") @QueryParam)
{
   //Calling DAO code. Everything is OK here. 
   //I can even see in debug that that return statement is executed successfully.
   return metricSamplesDataObject;
}
```

What can cause the connection to abort?

**EDIT**
I just came home and seems like the problem is relevant only while working at office.
So, the issue is that this specific method cause ClientAbortExcpetion at work only.
Could it be something related to the network security? Maybe because that amount of data?

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe add some code? This way all I can do is google your exception, but you don't need us for that.

Comment: *that* amount of data? The question doesn't say anything about a large (huge?) amount of data. If you want to know if that's it, that sounds like it's easy enough to test. 1) Generate the JSON. 2) Save it as a file 3) serve the file from your web-app.